# Apache2: internal redirects limit

Tags: php, apache

I'm developing a REST interface for an application. The interface interacts with a DB to log some data and perform a bit of statistics. After writing and testing with success my code I performed a bit of refactoring (I wrapped some of the DB interactions on separate functions and called them from the previous code) and then tested again and got this error:

```
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338128 2015] [core:error] [pid 9649] [client ::1:42760] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338139 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3534): [client ::1:42760] AH00121: r->uri = /rest/rest_functions.php
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338147 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3541): [client ::1:42760] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /rest/rest_functions.php
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338155 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3541): [client ::1:42760] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /rest/rest_functions.php
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338163 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3541): [client ::1:42760] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /rest/rest_functions.php
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338170 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3541): [client ::1:42760] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /rest/rest_functions.php
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338178 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3541): [client ::1:42760] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /rest/rest_functions.php
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338186 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3541): [client ::1:42760] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /rest/rest_functions.php
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338193 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3541): [client ::1:42760] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /rest/rest_functions.php
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338201 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3541): [client ::1:42760] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /rest/rest_functions.php
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338208 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3541): [client ::1:42760] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /rest/rest_functions.php
[Wed Dec 02 11:06:46.338216 2015] [core:debug] [pid 9649] core.c(3541): [client ::1:42760] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /rest/Jobmanager/next
```

My .htacces file (which is still the same which worked with the previous version) is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /rest/JobManager/rest_functions.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

From my (limited) understanding of Apache and PHP working nothing should have changed: I just added a couple of function calls *after* the rewrite process, so Apache shouldn't see any difference. It is obvious I'm wrong, but I can't see how.

EDIT: It seems the problem is unrelated to my PHP changes, I tested the unrefactored functions and got the same error. Still, the only thing I changed between yesterday (when the code worked) and today is that refactoring...

EDIT 2: I found the problem, somehow a second .htaccess file found its way in the repository and when I pulled this morning it placed itself in the parent directory starting a redirect loop.

Comment: I think you should go back to the last working stage and then refactor step by step, always applying tests so that you see that you have not broken anything.

Comment: I got back to the first step and got the same error. It seems that if I add a single function call to the one already in place the limit breaks...